# How to change properties of multiple UI elements

Tags: swift, user-interface, uikit

I'm trying to make a set of `UILabel`s bold, and figured it could be done with something like a CSS class. The only way I thought of though is subclassing `UILabel` and adding it as a Custom Class to each label:

```
import UIKit

class BoldLabel: UILabel {
    override internal var font: UIFont? {
        get {
            return UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(16.0)
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives an error "Getter for 'font' with Objective-C selector 'font' conflicts with getter for 'font' from superclass 'UILabel' with the same Objective-C selector". So is there a way to do it like this, or a different way to easily make a bunch of labels' fonts bold?

Comment: Check this link http://sunnycyk.com/2014/10/ios-subclass-uilabel-swift/, they make a subclass of UILabel as you. Then they call a setup method to custom the UILabel; In this setup method you can do something like : self.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12)

Then when you will assigned this class to your UILabels, they will have a bold font.

Comment: @AnthonyRn That's exactly what I needed, very simple. If you post an answer I can accept it

Comment: Wait I will show you a little example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class BoldLabel: UILabel {

//This method is call when you affect this class to a UILabel in your STORYBOARD
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    self.setup()
}

//This method is call when you programatically create an instance of this UILabel class
override init(frame:CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    self.setup()
}

func setup() {
    //All custom properties of this label class here
    self.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(28)
}
}
```

Results with UILabels from storyboard :

[image]